# How to stress test for 100 users with different username/password

Tags: jmeter

How do you stress test a web app that has login with 100 users, using jmeter? Is passing the csv the only way?

Answer (score 2):

[CSV](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) is the cleanest way, if they are unique username/passwords.

There are a slew of [functions](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/functions.html) that may help, depending on how you're generating the username/passwords

You can also use [Beanshell processors](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) to do javascript for creating username/passwords.

You also have the option of setting up [User Defined Variables](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables), but with 100 logins, this is tedious.

Comment: Hi,I tried using CSV with 2 users but the got error. The session seems to be timing out. Not sure why, does anyone know how to handle this issue?

Comment: Yes i am using it, how does cookie manager work does it set cookies that we add or the manage the whole in the app?

Comment: Is your probleme fixed ? If so give BlackGaff some love and accept is answer :)